# Robust and fast floating-point sum of squares

Tags: floating-point, lapack

I'd like to create a robust and fast *sum of squares*. A simple solution would be (in C++):

```
double sumOfSquares(const double *v, size_t n) {
    double r = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
        r += v[i]*v[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

This routine is not robust, as it fails to give a good result when `v[i]` is small or large (calculation under/overflows). And it is not the most accurate routine either, as we can sum numbers in a better way (like sorting before summing).

I've checked LAPACK's `DLASSQ` to get an inspiration (I've included the source code at the end of my question).

Basically, `DLASSQ` maintains a scale variable (this variable is calculated on-the-fly, it is the largest already seen element), and the array elements are scaled by this variable with division. This way the routine avoids under/overflow.

However, I don't like this solution, as:

- there are `n` divisions at least, which means that the routine is slow
- these divisions *may* reduce accuracy

I'm thinking about a possible improvement: the scale would always be a power of 2 (the largest already seen element rounded up to power-of-2). This way:

- As the reciprocal of a power-of-2 number is a power-of-2, I can store the reciprocal of the scale perfectly
- So division by scale can be replaced by a multiplication (so the routine will be much faster)
- This multiplication won't lose any accuracy, because it is just an exponent adjustment

My question is: is this a good idea? Is there a pitfall I don't see?

---

Here's the source code of `DLASSQ` (fortran code):

```
      SUBROUTINE DLASSQ( N, X, INCX, SCALE, SUMSQ )
*
*  -- LAPACK auxiliary routine (version 3.7.0) --
*  -- LAPACK is a software package provided by Univ. of Tennessee,    --
*  -- Univ. of California Berkeley, Univ. of Colorado Denver and NAG Ltd..--
*     December 2016
*
*     .. Scalar Arguments ..
      INTEGER            INCX, N
      DOUBLE PRECISION   SCALE, SUMSQ
*     ..
*     .. Array Arguments ..
      DOUBLE PRECISION   X( * )
*     ..
*
* =====================================================================
*
*     .. Parameters ..
      DOUBLE PRECISION   ZERO
      PARAMETER          ( ZERO = 0.0D+0 )
*     ..
*     .. Local Scalars ..
      INTEGER            IX
      DOUBLE PRECISION   ABSXI
*     ..
*     .. External Functions ..
      LOGICAL            DISNAN
      EXTERNAL           DISNAN
*     ..
*     .. Intrinsic Functions ..
      INTRINSIC          ABS
*     ..
*     .. Executable Statements ..
*
      IF( N.GT.0 ) THEN
         DO 10 IX = 1, 1 + ( N-1 )*INCX, INCX
            ABSXI = ABS( X( IX ) )
            IF( ABSXI.GT.ZERO.OR.DISNAN( ABSXI ) ) THEN
               IF( SCALE.LT.ABSXI ) THEN
                  SUMSQ = 1 + SUMSQ*( SCALE / ABSXI )**2
                  SCALE = ABSXI
               ELSE
                  SUMSQ = SUMSQ + ( ABSXI / SCALE )**2
               END IF
            END IF
   10    CONTINUE
      END IF
      RETURN
*
*     End of DLASSQ
*
      END
```

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Comment: Sounds good, but exponent adjustment doesn't loose accuracy: except if it underflows... Also ldexp() will do exponent adjustment, so multiplication/division doesn't really matter.

Comment: To locate relevant papers, search for "accurate dot product". There has been a fair amount of work on this in the 2000s.

Comment: @aka.nice: "exponent adjustment doesn't loose accuracy". Yes, that's what I'm saying too. I don't really want to use `ldexp()`, as it is slow. A multiplication is much faster.

Comment: @njuffa: Thanks for the recommendation! Dot product is a harder problem, as the individual products can be negative. But I'll check out papers on it, maybe I'll find something.